# Custom Block Product List Injection failed

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom-block, extend, di

I have to display a list of product on the product view, depending on its sku.

In order to do that, i have simply pasted the `Random.php` list example of `Magento_Catalog`.

But in order to find the proper product, i need to find the `attribut_set_id` of a specific `attribute_set_name`

So i injected an object:

```
<?php

namespace Extranet\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class Echantillon extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_attributeSetOptions;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options $attributeSetOptions,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_attributeSetOptions = $attributeSetOptions;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');

            $sku = $product->getSku();

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $this->_catalogLayer->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 100);
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $collection->setPage(1, 1);
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

}
```

But it tells me :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 7 passed to Extranet\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Echantillon::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options, array given,
```

I really don't understand that. I tried several different object, I even tried through the  `di.xml` to inject an object in the `$data` , and nop...

Edit: Note if i remove the `$attributeSetOptions` injection, my block works.

Final edit :

As everyone responded, it has something to do with var/

I tried my project on another server, and everything was ok. Weirdly, it came from my virtual machine: some classes were properly generated, other were not... Just restarted it this morning, and everything works... So sorry, not trully a Magento 2 PB, but i will know now that this kind of pb probably come from `/var`

Comment: remove var/generation/*

Comment: I did it about 1000 times :)

Answer (score 0):

Clear the var/generation and var/di folders

```
rm -rf var/generation var/di
```

enable developer mode (so the di configuration is not compiled)

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

search for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options` in your xml files. If there is not any preference configuration magento should inject the correct class

Comment: Developer mode already enable, var/ already well cleaned. I will try on a clean Magento 2 install...

Comment: do you have any di configuration for your own class Extranet\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList?

Comment: or another thing I've sometimes overlooked, if this class is extended by another class which calls the parent::__construct() with the wrong arguments

Comment: No. After 1 hour of not understanding, I tried to inject via di.xml the $data argument, and the $data is always empty. I have a lot of modules in my project, maybe something else is doing that...

Comment: It's trully a copy paste of the "Random" Block list of Magento_Catalog. I did nothing more for the moment.

Comment: hm ok, you should not need any di configuration at all for this class as long as you don't want to change the default attributes already configured in magento. Do you maybe have an opcode cache in place in the server? Restarting it might help then. Just an assumption

Comment: Not coming from an opcode cache, when i move my injection after $data for example, the error is changing. And another very weird thing: at first , i copy pasted into Extranet\Catalog\Block\Product (with correct namespace), the block wouldn't work... I had to move it to Extranet\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList... I still don't understand that either. Anyway, gonna try on a fresh install.

Comment: hm weird ;) could you maybe paste the layout xml where you instantiate the block and the di xml (if it contains anything about the block) into your question? really have no clue. Normally, this is a typical cause of rm var/generation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, indeed for this kind of error, I usually remove all folder in `var/`
For your task, maybe you could use catalog widget in BO. It allows to display a list of product with severals conditions.

Otherwise make a `custom select field in system config` to select your attributeSet and check in your block if your product `attributeSetId` match with your custom field in system config.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone responded, it has something to do with `var/`

I tried my project on another server, and everything was ok. Weirdly, it came from my virtual machine: some classes were properly generated, other were not... Just restarted it this morning, and everything works...